# Why does the table gets added always in the beginning of the page

Tags: tables, table-of-contents

When I add a table:

```
\begin{table}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{ | m{2cm} | m{6cm}| m{7cm} | } 
\rowcolor{Gray} 
\hline
Aspect
& Angular 
& React \\ 
\hline
Développeur
& Google
& Facebook \\ 
\hline
Langage
& Typescript
& Javascript ou JSX \\ 
\hline
Architecture
& Utilise une hiérarchie de composants
& Utilise des composants basés sur JSX \\ 
\hline
Databinding
& Utilise Liaison d'événement et des propriétés
& Gestion de l’état des composants avec l’architecture flux \\ 
\hline
Routage
& Utilise Liaison d'événement et des propriétés
& Gestion de l’état des composants avec l’architecture flux \\ 
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\caption{Comparaison entre Angular et React}
\label{angular_react}
\end{table}
```

It gets added in the beginning of the page despite the fact that in the source code I added it after the Angular paragraph:
[image]
However, when I remove:

```
\begin{table}
\end{table}
```

This kindof solves the issue. It displays the table in its place but it removes the caption:
[image]
This is really strange. I need the table in its place, with the caption. Howver, I couldn't solve this. Any help?

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Use `\begin{table}[!h]` (( and replace the  `center` environment with the `\centering` command to avoid spurious vertical spaces).

Comment: This is an FAQ: [How to influence the position of float environments like figure and table in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39017/5764)

Comment: In the answer @Werner refers to, you should read the part describing the effect of the optional argument to the `table`-command, and then try `[!hb]`, but you may end end up with the table on a different page. If you load the [caption](https://ctan.org/pkg/caption)-package you can remove the  table-environment, and use the `\captionof`-command (if you use [KOMA-script](https://ctan.org/pkg/koma-script)-class, they have an built-in `caption-of`-commands.